# What is the fastest Dijkstra implementation you know (in C++)?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I did recently attach the 3rd version of Dijkstra algorithm for shortest path of single source into my project.

I realize that there are many different implementations which vary strongly in performance and also do vary in the quality of result in large graphs. With my data set (> 100.000 vertices) the runtime varies from 20 minutes to a few seconds. Th shortest paths also vary by 1-2%.

Which is the best implementation you know?

**EDIT:**
My Data is a hydraulic network, with 1 to 5 vertices per node. Its comparable to a street map. I made some modifications to a already accelerated algorithm (using a sorted list for all remaining nodes) and now find to the same results in a fraction of time. I have searched for such a thing quite a while. I wonder if such a implementation already exists.

I can not explain the slight differences in results. I know that Dijkstra is not heuristic, but all the implementations seem to be correct. The faster solutions have the results with shorter paths. I use double precision math exclusively.

**EDIT 2:**
I found out that the differences in the found path are indeed my fault. I had inserted special handling for some vertices (only valid in one direction) and forgot about that in the other implementation.

**BUT** im still more than surprised that Dijkstra can be accelerated dramatically by the following change:
In general a Dijkstra algorithm contains a loop like:

```
MyListType toDoList; // List sorted by smallest distance 
InsertAllNodes(toDoList);
while(! toDoList.empty())
{
    MyNodeType *node = *toDoList.first();
    toDoList.erase(toDoList.first());
    ...
}
```

If you change this a little bit, it works the same, but performs better:

```
MyListType toDoList; // List sorted by smallest distance 
toDoList.insert(startNode);
while(! toDoList.empty())
{
    MyNodeType *node = *toDoList.first();
    toDoList.erase(toDoList.first());
    for(MyNeigborType *x = node.Neigbors; x != NULL; x++)
    {
        ...
        toDoList.insert(x->Node);
    }
}
```

It seems, that this modification reduces the runtime by a order not of magnitude, but a order of exponent. It reduced my runtime form 30 Seconds to less than 2. I can not find this modification in any literature. It's also very clear that the reason lies in the sorted list. insert/erase performs much worse with 100.000 elements that with a hand full of.

**ANSWER:**

After a lot of googling i found it myself. The answer is clearly:
**[boost graph lib](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html)**. Amazing - i had not found this for quite a while. If you think, that there is no performance variation between Dijkstra implementations, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time).

Comment: A friend of mine can implement Dijkstra in C++ in about 3 minutes. I haven't heard of any faster implementations.

Comment: I would suggest that you may want to check those implementations... if they are correct they should all return the same shortest path... Dijkstra's Algorithm isn't heuristic...

Comment: The differences in shortest paths may be a result of using double precision math, because of rounding errors when summing long sequences of doubles. A different order of summing may produce different errors. Can you test your implementations on integers?

Comment: Any one coming here and reading this should realise that the first variant is not Dijkstra's algorithm. Were the order of `toDoList` known a priori, one could just read out the shortest path straight away. The point is that `toDoList` should be a priority queue, where elements are added as they are discovered. The goal is to create a best-first search and the first version can't accomplish that.

Comment: @Unapiedra Yes. We can only guess, what `InsertAllNodes` does, but if it inserts the source node on 0 priority and the remaining ones on Infinity, it could work, even though slower, because the queue has to needlessly cope with all the vertices (plus the discovered). The big O complexity then get's really "fulfilled", as the queue is always at its max asymptotic size. If there is no path between the source and sink node, it could then pop the sink node (added by `InsertAllNodes`) and return the Infinity distance, instead of the exhausting of the queue like in the second variant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best implementations known for road networks (>1 million nodes) have query times expressed in **micro**seconds. See for more details the 9th DIMACS Implementation Challenge(2006). Note that these are not simply Dijkstra, of course, as the whole point was to get results faster.

Comment: I found the challenge you mentioned under
http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~challenge9/papers.shtml
very impressive. Thanks.

Comment: Also see http://algo2.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/english/1087.php for the Contraction Hierarchies method.

Answer (score 3):

May be I am not answering your question. My point is why to use Dijkstra when there are pretty much more efficient algorithms for your problem. If your graph fullfills the triangular property (it is an euclidian graph)

|ab| +|bc| > |ac|

(the distance from node a to node b plus distance from node b to node c is bigger than the distance from node a to node c) then you can apply the A* algorithm.
This algorithm is pretty efficient. Otherwise consider using heuristics.
The implementation is not the major issue. The algorithm to be used does matter.

Comment: I don't think you even *need* the triangular property. All you need is a good heuristic function. With a poor but valid heuristic, A* degrades to Dijkstra.

Comment: True. You are right. What I was telling was a possible admissible Heuristic.

Answer (score 2):

Two points I'd like to make:
1) Dijkstra vs A*
Dijkstra's algorithm is a dynamic programming algorithm, not an heuristic. A* is an heuristic because it also uses an heuristic function (lets say h(x) ) to "estimate" how close a point x is getting to the end point. This information is exploited in subsequent decisions of which nodes to explore next.

For cases such as an Euclidean graph, then A* works well because the heuristic function is easy to define (one can simply use the Euclidean distance, for example). However, for non Euclidean graphs it may be harder to define the heuristic function, and a wrong definition can lead to a non-optimal path.

Therefore, dijkstra has the advantage over A* which is that it works for any general graph (with the exception of A* being faster in some cases). It could well be that certain implementations use these algorithms interchangeably, resulting in different results.

2) The dijkstra algorithm (and others such as A*) use a priority queue to obtain the next node to explore. A good implementation may use a heap instead of a queue, and an even better one may use a fibonacci heap. This could explain the different run times.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I checked, Dijkstra's Algorithm returns an optimal solution.
All "true" implementations of Dijkstra's should return the same result each time.

Similarly, asymptotic analysis shows us that minor optimisations to particular implementations are not going to affect performance significantly as the input size increases.

Comment: Absulutely. The only difference may be when there are multiple "shortest paths" with the same (within a rounding error) lenght (cost). If some implementation fails to find a shortest path, it is buggy. Unless your ratio of node distances is extremely high (like 1e20 or more), you should definitely not see 1-2% percent difference, even with floats, not speaking about doubles.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on a lot of things.  How much do you know about your input data?  Is it dense, or sparse?  That will change which versions of the algorithm are the fastest.

If it's dense, just use a matrix.  If its sparse, you might want to look at more efficient data structures for finding the next closest vertex.  If you have more information about your data set than just the graph connectivity, then see if a different algorithm would work better like A*.

Problem is, there isn't "one fastest" version of the algorithm.