# Shortest path problem dijsktra with arc flags

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science, gis

On large graphs like 2M node road network, dijkstra can not solve shortest path problem in suitable time. We need to shortest path query execution time under 1 second and I am implementing arc flag way to make dijkstra fast. Is there anybody know about how to implement arc flags preprocessing and query. Preprocessing of arc flags has some different algorithm  I need fast one.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A fast algorithm to preprocess the graph and calculate arc flags?

Comment: See related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938338/what-is-the-fastest-dijkstra-implementation-you-know-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried A*?  It's a refinement of Dijkstra's algorithm that typically performs better; moreover, you can tune it to prefer search speed over optimality if that is an option.

Comment: So A* could guarantee optimality? News to me :O

Comment: Sure, A* is just Dijkstra with best first. If you use an admissible heuristic optimality is guaranteed.

Comment: The Arc-Flags algorithm mentioned significantly outperforms A*. See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.3778&rep=rep1&type=pdf for an example; you're talking about several orders of magnitude better(!)

Comment: Good grief, I was unaware of this stuff.  It's astonishing how far they've come with route planning.  Thanks for the reference.